# Earth API- Hide placemark desciption balloon on double click?

Tags: google-earth-plugin

I've got a number of placemarks displaying, each of which contains a description. On single click the desciption balloon displays which is fine, but on double click I want to flyto the coordinates and not display the balloon.  Is there code to turn off the balloon/placemark display on doubleclick?

Comment: Are you using the Winforms Managed Code API?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this would be to cancel the default behaviour using the `KmlEvent` `preventDefault()` method. You would then usually implement your own behaviour for the event in the same handler if required.

Something like the following.

```
// listen for all double-click events 
google.earth.addEventListener(ge.getWindow(), 'dblclick', function(e) {

    // get the target of the event
    var target = e.getTarget();

    // we are only interested in placemarks, so...
    if(target.getType() == 'KmlPlacemark') {

      // stop the default behaviour.
      // for placemarks the default behaviour is the balloon popping up
      e.preventDefault();

      // Add any custom behaviour here
    }
});
```